# ReactJS React Router params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, react-router

I currently have a React Router problem with my ReactJS project. I have a page that renders a view, inside the view is a .map function, which maps over all users and places the "first_name" inside an `<h4>` tag. The map functions works correctly for all users.

I want to be able to click on the user's first_name and it navigates to a new route with the _id as a parameter. The new component that you are navigated to will receive the _id and I will search the DB for their _id.

The intended routes:

```
| URL                 | Components |
|---------------------|------------|
| `/`                 | `Main`     |
| `/platform`         | `Platform` |
| `/platform/:userID` | `Editor`   |
```

Currently I have 3 files, the `routes.js` which holds all of the ReactRouter config. The `index.js` holds the rendered list of users from the DB. And the `editor.js` file that will receive a user's _id in the URL.

```
// Routes.js
import Main from './components/main';
import Home from './components/home';
import Platform from './components/platform';
import Editor from './components/editor';

<Route name="home" path="/" component={Main}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home} />
    <Route name="platform" path="platform/" component={Platform}>
        <Route name="user" path="/:userId" handler={Editor} />
    </Route>
</Route>


// Platform.js
{users.map(({_id, first_name, last_name}, index)=>
    <div>
        <Link to="user" params={{userId: _id}}>
            <h4 style={{fontFamily: 'Raleway', color: '#498EE0'}}>{first_name} {last_name} : {_id}</h4>
        </Link>
        <hr />
    </div>
)}
```

You should be able to click on the `Link` and the params are added onto the URL.

Currently when I try this, it simple appends `/user` onto my URL, so it appears `localhost:8080/user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `to` parameter like this -

```
<Link to={`/user/${_id}`}>
  <h4 style={{fontFamily: 'Raleway', color: '#498EE0'}}>{first_name} {last_name} : {_id}</h4>
</Link>
```

Comment: Thanks that now works, however it comes up with an error in the console: Warning: Location did not match any routes

Comment: You need to change your route also - <Route name="user" path="user/:userId" handler={Editor} />

Comment: Or if you prefer you can keep it like - <Link to={'/${_id}'}> and might accept this answer

Comment: Thanks so much, I also found that I'd nested the routes incorrrectly, so when having changed that and the changes you suggested, it works just fine :)